# Sorting Military Ranks then having output based on that rank in the next column. If statements possibly involved

Tags: excel-2010

If E7 and above (which includes E7 to E9 and O1 to O9), output MANAGER. If E6 and below (which include E1 to E6), output Worker Bee. I don't want to change Col A's order to make Col B. This is an example that would be for much longer lists so I need it to be automatic. Any ideas?  I tried multiple If statements but they kept recognizing the cell and not the rank. Thank you!

```
Col A  Col B
O6     MANAGER
E7     MANAGER
E3     Worker Bee
E1     Worker Bee
04     MANAGER
```

Comment: If this is unclear, please let me know, instead of just downgrading my question. I would be glad clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: Let me help you write a sentence, since it looks like you need help. Delete your first sentence, as it's caustic and not helpful. I agree with everything after that. Here's some background: I tried multiple If statements but they kept recognizing the cell and not the rank.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site where you can get help, this place is about helping people who are stuck on a problem and need help with working out the next step. Now sometimes people will provide answers as they like the challenge and being helpful, although this is not always the best thing to do as you may not be learning how to solve the issue yourself. If someone does take the time to provide an answer, it is polite to mark it solved, if the problem is not solved then leave a comment with more information so more help can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(LEFT(A3,1)="O","MANAGER",IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A3,1))>=7,"MANAGER","Worker Bee"))
```

Put this in cell B1 and auto fill down as required.

*I wrote this formula on my way home on the train using my mobile phone so it is untested , for any reason it's not working then use it as a starting point for your own formula.*

Edit: 
Formula now working. I have tested and updated the formula, I have changed it so it now accounts for the number after the letter being treated as text instead of a number value.